# How to uncheck mat-slide-toggle when I checked another mat-slide-toggle using Material Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-slider

I have this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmtqz6-bkgzjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-toggle-configurable-example.ts) project

Can you ask me any idea how to uncheck mat-slide-toggle `Title`  when I checked another mat-slide-toggle `Published date` and the opposite?

Comment: site, I saw you deleted your recent array-sorting question, so I thought I'd just quickly mention here that [MDN shows how](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort objects by a particular property (immediately before the 'examples' section). For your particular case, I think you'd use something like `myObjects.sort((a, b) => a.Date > b.Date ? -1 : 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good morning :D. You forgot to put in your code the [(ngModel)]="yourVariable" to receive the value when they change!

I recommend that you read more about forms and reactive forms:

[Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)
[Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Here is you demo fixed: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmtqz6-xq1may?file=src/app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.html)